# How to sum the value of keys in subcollection within a range using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, nosql

I have a collection:

```
{ date: datetime(2017, 10, 18, 0, 0, 0),
  count: {
    S: 7,
    A: 8
  }
}
{ date: datetime(2017, 10, 19, 0, 0, 0),
  count: {
    A: 9
  }
}
{ date: datetime(2017, 10, 20, 0, 0, 0),
  count: {
    A: 9,
    B: 8
  }
}
```

How can I use the mongo aggregation framework to sum these count in the collection within a range(e.g. 2 days), and get the output looks like:

```
{
    count: {
        S: { in_2_days: 7, in_3_days: 7 },
        A: { in_2_days: 16, in_3_days: 26 },
        B: { in_2_days: 0, in_3_days: 8 }
    }
}
```

P.S. I had been thinking about output like this:

```
{
    in_days: 2
    count: {
        S: 7,
        A: 16
    }
}
{
    in_days: 3
    count: {
        S: 7,
        A: 26,
        B: 8
    }
}
```

But this is not what I want.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Do you only have 'S','A','B' variables in the collection ? or can be many?

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul it can be many

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution but I am giving a try, let me know if this helps you :

I am assuming your collection is in a txt file named abc.txt:
As i already commented that try this solution if your collection only have 'S','A','B' variables :

```
import re
pattern="([S]:\s(\d{0,26}))|([A]:\s(\d{0,26}))|([B]:\s(\d{0,26}))|(count)"
pattern_dict={}
final_pattern=[]
count=[]

with open("abc.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        finding=re.finditer(pattern,line)
        for match in finding:

            if 'S' not in pattern_dict:

                if match.group(2)!= None:
                    pattern_dict["S"]=[int(match.group(2))]
            else:
                if match.group(2) != None:
                    pattern_dict["S"].append(int(match.group(2)))
            if pattern_dict not in final_pattern:

                final_pattern.append(pattern_dict)

            if 'A' not in pattern_dict:
                if match.group(4) != None:
                    pattern_dict["A"]=[int(match.group(4))]
            else:
                if match.group(4) != None:
                    pattern_dict["A"].append(int(match.group(4)))
            if pattern_dict not in final_pattern:

                final_pattern.append(pattern_dict)

            if 'B' not in pattern_dict:
                if match.group(6) != None:
                    pattern_dict['B']=[int(match.group(6))]
            else:
                if match.group(6) != None:
                    pattern_dict['B'].append(int(match.group(6)))
            if pattern_dict not in final_pattern:

                final_pattern.append(pattern_dict)

            if match.group(7)!=None:
                count.append(match.group(7))



dict1=final_pattern[0]

sum_of_items=[(k,v) for k,v in dict1.items()]


count2=0


for item in sum_of_items:
    if len(item[1])==1:


            print("for {} total days {} = {} ".format(item[0],len(count),"".join(str(i) for i in item[1])))



    else:
        count1 = 0
        for i in range(len(item[1])):
            count1 += 1

            print("for {} total days {} = {}".format(item[0],count1,sum(item[1][:i + 1])))
```

Comment: Hmm, Thanks! But Actually I want to use mongo aggregation framework(I mentioned it in the post) to get output like that

Answer (score 0):

I finally use the aggregation framework to sum and write some python code to "shape" the data into the form I want.